# Getting current path in variable and using it

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to extract the current path in a variable and use it later on in the script

Something like:

```
myvar = pwd
```

Later on:

```
cd myvar
```

But my bash skills have rusted over the years.

How would i go on about doing that?

Comment: In addition to the answers to your actual question, you can run commands in a different directory with a sub-shell, like: **(cd xyz ; rm temp.$$)**

Comment: very cool NVRM.
After I write my script and fight with the varibale assign I just try your solution and warp my code with () and it just work ! ( I deleted like a 7 line thank to that )

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
myvar="$PWD"
cd "$myvar"
```

(Quotes are necessary if your path contains whitespaces.)

Comment: `$(pwd)` may be more accurate than `$PWD` (but may sometimes give a different path than you expect).

Comment: And quotes aren't required in the assignment unless there's whitespace in the *command* -- hence, this works fine: **myvar=$PWD**

Comment: Just to mention it out for exporting resolved path of dir relative to current oath the best way i found was like: `export directory=$(realpath "$PWD/../../")`

Answer (score 14):

Something like this should work:

```
myvar=`pwd`
# ...
cd $myvar
```

Comment: Since he explicitely asks about bash I'd use the alternate syntax: `$(pwd)` as it's easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: There is nothing bash-specific about `$(…)`; it can and arguably should be used in all instances

Comment: @sgm: I didn't know that. Indeed it seems POSIX already defines that, so even less reason to use the old backticks.

Answer (score 8):

in bash

```
$ a=$(pwd)
```

Comment: Thanks! The "$pwd" did not work for me, but this did.

Comment: why does this print the directory and a "No such file or directory" error?

Answer (score 5):

Ind addition to the `pwd` command and the `$PWD` environment variable, I'd also suggest you look into `pushd`/`popd`:

```
/$ pushd /usr
/usr /
/usr$ pushd /var/log
/var/log /usr /
/var/log$ popd
/usr /
/usr$ popd
/
/$
```

Comment: Plus, check out the **cd -** command (with a dash/hyphen), and the **$OLDPWD** auto-variable.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:

```
currentdir=$(cd -)
printf "Generating content at $currentdir\n"
```