# Save current directory in variable using Bash?

Tags: bash, variables, directory

What I'm trying to do is find the current working directory and save it into a variable, so that I can run `export PATH=$PATH:currentdir+somethingelse`. I'm not entirely sure if they have a variable that contains cwd by default.

How do I save the current directory in variable using Bash?

Comment: so to save it to a variable would I do mydir=. ?

Comment: yup just tested with mydir=. then ls $mydir -but it's relative so it will be the pwd from wherever you run it

Comment: Oh, I had some spaces. t.t ${PWD} should've worked. haha. ... whoops

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting current path in variable and using it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1636363/608639), [How to get a variable to have the current dir path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35189157/608639), etc.

Answer (score 280, accepted):

This saves the absolute path of the current working directory to the variable `cwd`:

```
cwd=$(pwd)
```

In your case you can just do:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)+somethingelse
```

Comment: for some reason if I change to another dir this updates the `cwd` variable too. Like if it's calling the `pwd` function each time...

https://dpaste.de/Kn7F

How can I avoid that?

Comment: `$CWD` may be a special (reserved) environment variable in your shell. Try a different name instead, such as `$CWD_MY_VAR`

Comment: Using backticks does the same.

Comment: Why not just use `"$PWD"`?

Answer (score 37):

I have the following in my .bash_profile:

```
function mark {
    export $1=`pwd`;
}
```

so anytime I want to remember a directory, I can just type, e.g. *mark there* .

Then when I want to go back to that location, I just type *cd $there*

Comment: Works well but for paths with spaces, e.g. "Google Drive" you have to do ```cd "$foo"``` for the whole path to be read

Comment: To get around the problem with spaces in the path change ```export $1=`pwd` ``` to  ```export $1="`pwd`" ``` and then when calling such paths use ```cd "$foo"``` instead of just ```cd $foo```

Comment: mercergeoinfo: Strictly speaking, the quotes in `export $1="\`pwd\`"` are not needed, since word splitting does not happen at the right-hand side of an assignment, although quoting of expansions is good to get used to as a habit.

Comment: See also [`cdable_vars`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39839346/1518546) to type just `cd there`

Answer (score 14):

current working directory variable ie full path /home/dev/other

```
dir=$PWD
```

print the full path

```
echo $dir
```

Answer (score 6):

for a **relative** answer, use `.`

test with:

```
$ myDir=.
$ ls $myDir
$ cd /
$ ls $myDir
```

The first `ls` will show you everything in the current directory, the second will show you everything in the root directory (`/`).

Answer (score 6):

Your assignment has an extra `$`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:${PWD}:/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 4):

On a BASH shell, you can **very simply** run:

```
export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/somethingelse
```

No need to save the current working directory into a variable...

Answer (score 0):

One more variant:

```
export PATH=$PATH:\`pwd`:/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell in-build variable `PWD`, like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$PWD+somethingelse
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to solution of `mark` with some checking of variables. Also I prefer not to use `$variable` but rather the same string I saved it under

save your folder/directory using save dir `sdir myproject` and go back to that folder using goto dir `gdir myproject`

in addition checkout the workings of native `pushd and popd` they will save the current folder and this is handy for going back and forth. In this case you can also use `popd` after `gdir myproject` and go back again

```
# Save the current folder using sdir yourhandle to a variable you can later access the same folder fast using gdir yourhandle

function sdir {
    [[ ! -z "$1" ]] && export __d__$1="`pwd`";
}
function gdir {
    [[ ! -z "$1" ]] && cd "${!1}";
}
```

another handy trick is to combine the two pushd/popd and sdir and gdir wher you replace the cd in the goto dir function in pushd. This enables you to also fly back to your previous folder when making the jump to the saved folder.

```
# Save the current folder using sdir yourhandle to a variable you can later access the same folder fast using gdir yourhandle

function sdir {
    [[ ! -z "$1" ]] && export __d__$1="`pwd`";
}
function gdir {
    [[ ! -z "$1" ]] && pushd "${!1}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With hint from @gerardw [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26384751/713573) I added the following in `.bashrc`, this has persistence also:

```bash
function mark {
  cur=`pwd`;
  echo "export cur_project=$cur" > ~/.cur_project
  . ~/.cur_project
}
. ~/.cur_project

alias curp='cd $cur_project'
```

So `cur_project` variable is available in `.bashrc` or bash command any time.

This `alias curp='cd $cur_project'` is just in case someone wants to switch to current project any time.