# How to get a variable to have the current dir path?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a really simple function in bash script that tells me the current directory. However it gives the error `bash: =/home/users/abc: No such file or directory` $currentdir is empty.

Why is this happening? I also tried

```
$currentdir=`pwd`
```

and that didn't work too.

This is a similar question [Bash: current directory variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275013/bash-current-directory-variable) and I tried this but it didn't solve my problem.

```
xpwd() {
    $currentdir=$(pwd)
    echo "current dir is $currentdir"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to set a variable, you don't use the `$`:

```
currentdir=`pwd`
```

The `$` is for when you want to do a variable substitution.

Comment: No mention of how a) `$()` is preferable and b) there is an environment variable `$PWD` making the assignment kind of useless anyway?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Thanks for telling me about `$PWD`; I wasn't aware of it. As for `$()`, I probably should have used that.

Answer (score -1):

Assigning to a variable is without the '$' sign.  Using the value is with the '$' sign.

```
currentdir=`pwd`
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
currentdir=`pwd`
```

(remove the `$`)