# Store current directory in variable and use a variable to store the path developed from the previous variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, pwd

I need to store the current directory into a variable, so i did:

```
$current_path='pwd'
```

Till this point it is correct, but if I use the below one:

```
MY_FOLDER=$current_path/subFolder1/subFolder2/MyFolder/
```

and do `$MY_FOLDER` I am getting an error:

```
pwd/subFolder1/subFolder2/MyFolder/ : No such file or directory
```

Can you please tell me how do i use this in shell scripting?
(This might be basics but this is my first scripting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting current path in variable and using it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1636363/608639), [Save current directory in variable using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13275013/608639), [How to get a variable to have the current dir path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35189157/608639), etc. And maybe [How to set current working directory to the directory of the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3349105/608639)

Answer (score 1):

When you write `$variable` at the prompt, the shell will interpolate its value and parse it. The error message you get says that the value is not a valid command name.

Also, the dollar sign in your first assignment is incorrect (I guess you transcribed that incorrectly) and the value you assign is the literal string `pwd` which is probably not the name of a directory in the current directory; I'm guessing you intended to run the *command* `pwd` and store its output.

However, Bash already stores the current working directory in a variable named `PWD`; so there should be no need to separately call the external utility `pwd`.

(Maybe you wanted to write `` `pwd` `` with backticks instead of regular single quotes `'pwd'`? That would be valid syntax, though it's obsolescent and, as you discovered, hard to read. The modern equivalent syntax is `$(pwd)`.)

You should also avoid upper case for your variable names; uppercase is reserved for system variables. (This is a common mistake even in some respected shell scripting tutorials.)

I guess you actually want

```
current_path=$(pwd)  # needless here, but shows the correct syntax
my_folder=$PWD/subFolder1/subFolder2/MyFolder/
```

Attempting to run the directory as a command is still an error. If this directory contains an executable named `foo` with correct permissions, then

```
"$my_folder/"foo
```

will execute that script. It's not clear what you expected your command to do; perhaps you are looking fo

```
cd "$my_folder"
```

instead? (Notice also the [quotes](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) which are optional in this particular case if the output from `pwd` does not contain any shell metacharacters; but you want your scripts to also work correctly when that is not true.)